# Keep bitmap inside a rectangle - android

Tags: android, bitmap

I am trying to understand the basics of moving objects on the screen etc. I have a bitmap and I am moving that bitmap on the screen. How can I keep the bitmap inside the rectangle and still move it. I would like to put the bitmap in a rectangle as that will help in collision detection with other objects. Below is my code so far. 
Thanks

```
 Bitmap bitmap1 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.yellow_ball);
      x1 = 0;
      y1 = 100;

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {


 if(x1 < canvas.getWidth()){

     x1 += 5;
    }

    else{
     x1 = 0;
      }

    canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap1, x1, y1, null);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have the basic idea.

First, decide where you want to move the object to.

Then compare the new X coordinate to the rectangle's left and right bounds,
and if the new X coordinate is outside of the rectangle's bounds, reset the coordinate to the bound that it is exceeding.

Then, do the same for the Y coordinate.

Finally, move your bitmap to the adjusted X and Y coordinates.

I wrote code to do this a while back, see https://github.com/rfreedman/android-constrained-drag-and-drop-view for an example.